# Bypass scroll event from uiwebview to parent view

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, scroll

I have a problem about scroll event

after I added a subview UIWebView to a table cell

[cell.contentView addSubview:webview];

if scroll vertical inside webview, the webview is scrolling, the parent table cell is static, I want to bypass the scrolling event to parent view(cell) and let table scroll vertical

How to do the job?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply need the Web View to display content; and not handle user interactions in any way, you simply need to disableUserInteraction for the webview;

```
webView.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
```

This will pass any user interactions down to the parent view, which in your case will be the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling scrolling of webview

```
for (id subview in mWebView.subviews)
    if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).scrollEnabled= NO;
```